# Bootstrap dropdown works only for one page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am having an issue with Boostrap dropdown.

See [www.beaba-bienetre.fr](http://www.beaba-bienetre.fr)

The dropdown menu (named "Mon offre") only works for the index.php page, although boostrap.min.js appears to be launched on every page.

Any idea ?

thanks, Mathieu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert script tags multiple times in footer on other pages.

Comment: Bad refactoring indeed...Thanks !